# NSG rules attached to all VM under a subscription

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-node-sdk

I have a requirement where I need to get NSG rules attached to all VM/NIC under a subscription using azure node SDK. I went through Node [doc](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/azure-arm-compute/latest/VirtualMachines.html#listAll) but didn't find any suitable method to do so. Is there anything that I'm missing?

I have tried below snippet to get all VM but it didn't include NSG details, is there any specific method in ComputeManagementClient/NetworkManagementClient which will return me the NSG details corresponding to VM or at least return NSG for a particular VM? Thanks in Advance.

```
function getVMDetailsAll(callback) {
return computeClient.virtualMachines.listAll(callback)
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind guys, the documentation really shocks, I went through the source code and figured out the way to query and run few costume code to filter

```
function getNSGAll(callback) {
  return networkClient.networkSecurityGroups.listAll(callback);
}
```